# The following loop runs for infinite time. why?

Tags: c, file, infinite

```
while(0==0)

 {
      ch = getc(f);

      while(ch != '\n')
      {
           i++;
           ch = getc(f);
           printf("hi ");
      }

      if(ch == EOF)
      break;
 }
```

This loop runs for infinite time printing hi. The file looks like this:-

1 3 8 2 4

2 3 3

3

Comment: My telepathic powers tell me that it's because you declared `char  ch;` instead of `int ch;`.

Comment: Yeah it is a char ch.

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do, otherwise the test for `ch == EOF` will never be true. Also I just realised that there's another logic bug in the inner loop - see comments below.

Comment: Even using `ìnt` you program is flawed. Ask yourself what happens if you encounter EOF while still inside the `while` loop?

Comment: Insted of writing `while (0==0)` write `while (1)`, this is the usual way of doing it. It's strictly equivalent, but `0 == 0` just looks strange.

Comment: It is wrong, in general. This loop will never end, because at the line `if (ch == EOF)` you always have a `ch` equal to `\n` (otherwise, the while wouldn't stop).

Answer (score 1):

You can take input as:

```
while((ch = getc(f)) != EOF)
```

or

```
while(scanf(" %c ",&c) != EOF)
```

instead of infinite `while(0==0)`

and remove the `break` condition instead.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of fields read and converted. It does not return `EOF`, so use `!= 0)`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, I've actually used this and this works.

Comment: There seems to be a discrepancy between the MS VC2008 and Linux documentation on `scanf`. In Linux it returns `EOF` if end of input is reached before a conversion could take place; in VC if _format_ is a NULL pointer, the invalid parameter handler is invoked, which can allow the program to continue and then `scanf` returns `EOF`. In all other cases VC `scanf` returns 0. To handle both environments, use `while(scanf(" %c ",&c) == 1)`

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't know that. I use Linux environment anyway. Also, I never noticed this ambiguity in behavior of scanf, anytime before I was writing for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is EOL ('\n') at end of the file? Otherwise your while(ch != '\n') has no reason to stop after reading last line.

Answer (score 0):

0 will always be equals to 0. this is originating your infinite cicle. Use this instead:

```
 {while(scanf(" %c ",&c) != EOF)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(0==0)
```

Is a very strange notation, do this:

```
while(1)
```

To find out why your loop never stops (you are correct in that), lets observe the  possible circumstances

1. Your `getc(f)` retrieves any char not `/n` and not `EOF`. Proceed to the second `while` loop.
2. Your `getc(f)` retrieves `/n`. Restart the first `while` loop. (since `ch` is not `EOF`)
3. Your `getc(f)` retrieves `EOF`. Proceed to the second `while` loop.

In the second while loop:

1. `getc(f)` retrieves `/n`. Restart the first while loop (`ch` is not `EOF`)
2. `getc(f)` retrieves any char but `/n` and `EOF`. Restart the second `while` loop.
3. `getc(f)` retrieves `EOF`. Restart the second `while` loop.

You see that under no possibile scenario the outer `while` loop can break.